# Is it possible to "yield return null" in an IEnumerator in F#?

Tags: unity-game-engine, f#, c#-to-f#

For example in C#:

```
public IEnumerator MyFunc() {
  yield return null
}
```

This is what I tried in F#:

```
seq {
  yield null
} :?> IEnumerator
```

After compiling and then using ILSpy to take a look at what it compiles down to, the `yield` keyword is nowhere to be found.
Is this not possible to do in F#? The reason I'm using this instead of `Async` is because of Unity compatibility.

Comment: you can use async in Unity

Comment: Doesn't unity have dodgy Task support? UniTask seems to exist to workaround those issues

Comment: _"the yield keyword is nowhere to be found"_ this is expected, `yield` is just a syntax sugar, the compiler should convert the function into an IEnumerator class. For c# assembly, ILSpy knows how to decompile the class back, it just doesn't work for f# assembly.

Comment: @Edward UniTask is a cool extension that provides more seamless Unity integration and bridging between Coroutines and async code as well as main thread dispatching ... in general Unity's c# layer ... well is c# so async Task is as supported as anywhere else .. the most common issue is only the main thread limitations of most of Unity's API

Comment: Why does it matter whether you see the `yield` keyword?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I think it's mainly just confusion / wanting to confirm that it actually does what it should and will work as expected

Comment: During my tests I thought ``yield null`` wasn't doing the same behaviour, but perhaps I was just testing wrong.

I'll have to take a closer look at it again, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# `yield` keyword is not a thing in the underlying MSIL. It only exists in C#, and upon encountering it, the compiler unfolds your method in a clever way and creates a class with clever state transitions from it, and makes that class expose the `IEnumerable` interface.

If you decompile the C# code, the decompiler would usually look for that specific pattern of code that the C# compiler creates and decompiles it back to the `yield` keyword. But there is no `yield` keyword in the compiled code.

F# compiler does a very similar thing, but it uses a pattern that's different from what the C# compiler does. And so the decompiler can't reconstruct the `yield` keyword. Perhaps some day decompilers will support F# computation expressions. One can hope.

But your code does work exactly as you intend it to: creates a sequence with a `null` in it. It's easy to verify for yourself in REPL:

```
- let s : seq<string> =
-   seq {
-     yield "x"
-     yield null
-     yield "y"
-   }
-
- List.ofSeq s;;
val s: seq<string>
val it: string list = ["x"; null; "y"]
```

Comment: Didn't realize the underlying MSIL would be different. This clears up my misunderstandings, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can yield null in F#. The compiler will [build a state machine](https://mazeez.dev/posts/csharp-yield), just like the C# compiler does. (There's no `yield` keyword in IL.)

Example:

```
seq {
    yield "a"
    yield null
    yield "b"
} |> printfn "%A"
```

Output:

```
seq ["a"; null; "b"]
```

Decompiled to C# using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfCBTAjgAgN4FgBQGhGAngJYrAwYBEAhtfkSeZRgHYCuwwjRZFVagCMGeAL4ZEAPgwAHAE6k2AFzBsaAUgCC1IA===):

```cs
        public override int GenerateNext(ref IEnumerable<object> next)
        {
            switch (pc)
            {
                default:
                    pc = 1;
                    current = "a";
                    return 1;
                case 1:
                    pc = 2;
                    current = null;
                    return 1;
                case 2:
                    pc = 3;
                    current = "b";
                    return 1;
                case 3:
                    pc = 4;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
            }
            current = null;
            return 0;
        }
```